# How can I export a database to Azure in SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2008?

Tags: sql, azure, ssms

I'm trying to export a database to Azure using the most recent version of SSMS 2008, and I'm having trouble because I don't have the options listed under "Tasks" that the tutorials I've found indicate that I should select.

This is what I'm supposed to see:
https://technobuff.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/111913_1726_dacpacandba1.png?w=1176

This is what I see:

[image]

I've spent way too long trying to find more information on this and have come up blank. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing to be able to export the database?

Comment: Can you not just create a full backup of the DB to a BAK file and then restore that where you need it or with a different DB name? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly but you could do that and probably much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on "`Generate Scripts`" and follow the instructions.

Under "`Set Scripting Options`" click on "`Advanced`" and make sure that under "`Type of data to script`" you select "`Schema and Data`". This will create a script what you'll be able to use to create a database with all your original data.

I have also read that you need one of the newer Server Management Studio (I do not know which one exaclty) to be able to deploy directly to Azure so maybe if you just upgrade your SSMS you'll have those options.